# Sales taxed amount in Accounts Receivable?

Tags: accounting, limited-liability-company, sales-tax, quickbooks, accounts

When I enter a new invoice for a client, for example $1062.50 ($1000 + MA sales tax) do BOTH Accounts Receivable AND Sales Tax Payable go up by the following?

Accounts Receivable +1062.50
Sales Tax Payable +62.50

This just makes me feel like I am counting the 62.50 twice, which feels wrong.

Or is it like this?

Accounts Receivable +1000.00
Sales Tax Payable +62.50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A receivable is a positive entry, an asset.
The tax due is a negative, an amount you owe.

The two add to $1000 if you add them up.